# Powershell doesn't return output when asked to be verbose in Azure App Service creation script

Tags: powershell, azure, paas, uipath

I want to create/configure an App Service in Azure. When trying to use the Azure App Service Installation Script (provided by the Software developer) there shows up an issue. I want to push the software from my local machine to the precreated Azure Paas App Service

This is the error:

> .\Publish-Orchestrator.ps1 
>   `-action Deploy`
>   -package "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\RoboOrchestrator\RoboOrchestrator.zip" `
>   -publishSettingsPath "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\RoboOrchestrator\NLRoboTest-Orchestrator.PublishSettings"

**That fails with an error.

> Deploy-Package : 
>   Failed to deploy package C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\RoboOrchestrator\RobotOrchestrator.zip
>   At C:\users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\RoboOrchestrator\Publish-Orchestrator.ps1:93 char:5
>   +     Deploy-Package $package $publishSettings.PublishSettings
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Deploy-Package**

If i try to debug the Powershell to get some more feedback with VERBOSE, nothing shows up.

```
    Write-Host "`nExecuting command:`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host "msdeploy.exe $args`n"

    $shouldContinue = $unattended -or (Prompt-ForContinuation)

    if (!$shouldContinue) {
        Write-Host "`nExiting...`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Exit 0
    }

    Write-Host ""
    #
     $proccess = Start-Process $script:msDeployExe -ArgumentList $args -Wait -NoNewWindow  -PassThru -verbose **>C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\RoboOrchestrator\msdeploysync-verbose.log**

    if ($proccess.ExitCode) {
      Write-Error "`nFailed to deploy package $package"
      Exit 1
    }

    Write-Host "`nPackage $package deployed successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
```

What can I do to get it start talking?

kind regards

Comment: Problem solved, they finally found out, that they gave me the wrong script.